# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $n^2 - q^k$ is not a square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, solution-verification, perfect-numbers

**Problem Statement**

Prove the following proposition.

> If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $n^2 - q^k$ is not a square.

**Motivation**

Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.  Then $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

By [Pomerance, et al.](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper10.pdf), we know that $q^k < n^2$, so that $n^2 - q^k$ is a positive integer.  Also, since $n^2$ is a square and $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then
$$n^2 - q^k \equiv 1 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 4.$$

**My Attempt**

Suppose that $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, and that $n^2 - q^k = s^2$, for some $s \geq 2$.

Then
$$n^2 - s^2 = q^k = (n + s)(n - s)$$
so that we obtain
$$\begin{cases}
{q^{k-v} = n + s \\
q^v = n - s}
\end{cases}$$
where $v$ is a positive integer satisfying $0 \leq v \leq (k-1)/2$.
It follows that we have the system
$$\begin{cases}
{q^{k-v} + q^v = q^v (q^{k-2v} + 1) = 2n \\
q^{k-v} - q^v = q^v (q^{k-2v} - 1) = 2s}
\end{cases}$$

Since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$, from the first equation it follows that $v=0$, so that we obtain
$$\begin{cases}
{q^k + 1 = 2n \\
q^k - 1 = 2s}
\end{cases}$$
which yields
$$n = \frac{q^k + 1}{2} < q^k.$$
Lastly, note that the inequality $q<n$ has been proved by [Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591), [Dris (2017)](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-4/01-13/), and [Starni (2018)](http://nntdm.net/volume-24-2018/number-1/5-9/), so that we are faced with the inequality
$$q < n < q^k.$$
This implies that $k>1$.

Finally, notice that $k>1$ contradicts the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture, while $n<q^k$ contradicts the Dris Conjecture.

**Question**

> Is it possible to remove the reliance of this proof on the truth of either the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture or the Dris Conjecture?

Comment: What does special prime means?

Comment: @greedoid, the special prime $q$ is also called the *Euler prime*.  It is the prime divisor which occurs to an odd exponent in the factorization of the odd perfect number $q^k n^2$.  (That is, we have $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to finish the proof without appealing to any conjecture.

If $q^k n^2$ is a perfect number with $\operatorname{gcd}(q,n)=1$, we have
$$
\sigma(q^k) \sigma(n^2) = 2 q^k n^2.
$$
We know that $\sigma(q^k) = (q^{k+1}-1)/(q-1)$ and you've shown that $n = (q^k + 1)/2$,  so we can conclude that
$$
2(q^{k+1}-1) \sigma(n^2) = (q-1) q^k (q^k + 1)^2.\tag{$*$}
$$
Consider the GCD of $q^{k+1}-1$ with the right-hand side:
$$
\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1, (q-1) q^k (q^k + 1)^2) \le (q-1)\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1,q^k+1)^2,
$$
since $q^k$ is coprime to $q^{k+1} - 1$.

Noticing that $q^{k+1} - 1$ = $q(q^k + 1) - (q + 1)$, we find $\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1,q^k+1) = \operatorname{gcd}(q+1,q^k+1)$, which is $q+1$ because $k$ is odd.

Thus
$$
\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1, (q-1) q^k (q^k + 1)^2) \le (q-1)(q+1)^2.
$$
Since $k\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and you have shown $k \gt 1$, we have $k \ge 5$.  If $(*)$ holds, the left-hand side of the inequality must be $q^{k+1}-1$, which is then greater than $q^5$.  But the right-hand side is less than $q^4$, so this is impossible.

Comment: Very nice, @FredH!

I think there is a typo in
$$
\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1, (q-1) q^k (q^k + 1)^2) \le (q-1)\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1,q^k+1)^2,
$$
shouldn't that be
$$
\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1, (q-1) q^k (q^k + 1)^2) \le (q-1)\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1,(q^k+1)^2)?
$$

Comment: Also, can you comment more on why the left-hand side of the inequality
$$
\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1, (q-1) q^k (q^k + 1)^2) \le (q-1)(q+1)^2
$$
must be $q^{k+1} - 1$?  That is, it appears that you are claiming that
$$\operatorname{gcd}(q^{k+1}-1, (q-1) q^k (q^k + 1)^2) = q^{k+1} - 1.$$

Comment: Not a typo, I'm just using $\operatorname{gcd}(a,bc) \le \operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\operatorname{gcd}(a,c)$.

Comment: If $(*)$ holds, $q^{k+1}-1$ is a divisor of the RHS, so their GCD is $q^{k+1}-1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your follow-up comments, @FredH!  I think I get it now.  =)

Comment: Would you mind shooting me an e-mail at josearnaldobdris AT gmail DOT com, @FredH, I need to discuss something with you.  Thanks!  =)