# Is it possible to improve on these bounds for $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, totient-function, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with *special/Eulerian prime* $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Denote the *Euler-totient function* of the positive integer $x$ by $\varphi(x)$, and the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

**MOTIVATION**

From the following source:
[Advanced Problem H-661, On Odd Perfect Numbers, Proposed by J. L´opez Gonz´alez, Madrid, Spain and F. Luca, Mexico (Vol. 45, No. 4, November 2007), Fibonacci Quarterly](https://www.fq.math.ca/Problems/Advanced_Problems_NOV2009.pdf), we have the bounds
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{1}{2}.$$

However, we also have
$$\frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}.$$
Notice that
$$\frac{4}{5} \leq \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k} = \frac{q^k \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{q}\bigg)}{q^k} = \frac{q - 1}{q} < 1.$$
Therefore, we have the bounds
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n},$$
and
$$\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} \leq \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{1}{2},$$
which implies that
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{5}{8}.$$

WolframAlpha gives the rational approximation
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} \approx 0.4600409433626.$$

Harking back from this [answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3285414/28816), we have the following proposition:

> **THEOREM A:** Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.  Then we have the following implication:
> $$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{2} \implies q = 5.$$

> **PROOF:** Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, and suppose that
> $$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{2}.$$
> From the equation and lower bound for $\varphi(N)/N$
> $$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$$
> and the equation
> $$\frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k} = \frac{q - 1}{q},$$
> we get the lower bound
> $$2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1} < \frac{2\varphi(n)}{n} = x.$$
> This implies that we have the upper bound
> $$q < \frac{x}{x-1} < \frac{2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}}{\bigg(2\cdot\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1}\bigg) - 1}$$
> which can be solved using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20q%20%3C%20(2(120%2F(217(zeta(3))))(q%2F(q-1)))%2F(2(120%2F(217(zeta(3))))(q%2F(q-1))%20-%201)%20for%20q), yielding the upper bound
> $$q < \frac{217\zeta(3)}{217\zeta(3) - 240} \approx 12.5128,$$
> from which it follows that $q=5$, since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  **QED**

Note that the estimate
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{2}$$
was used to justify
$$0 < q < \frac{x}{x-1}.$$

---

We now endeavor/attempt to prove the estimate
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{2}.$$

To do so, consider the equation
$$\frac{2q}{q+1}=\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}.$$
(This is not random guesswork - it emanates from considering the inequalities
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} < \frac{n^2}{\varphi(n^2)} = \frac{n}{\varphi(n)}$$
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} = \frac{2q^k}{\sigma(q^k)} \leq \frac{2q}{q+1},$$
and determining whether the right-hand sides are equal.)

Since $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $(q+1)/2$ is an integer, so that we may rewrite
$$\frac{2q}{q+1}=\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}$$
as
$$q\varphi(n)=\bigg(\frac{q+1}{2}\bigg)\cdot{n}.$$

Since $\gcd(q,n)=1$, then $n \mid \varphi(n)$.  This contradicts
$$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}=\frac{q+1}{2q}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2q} \leq \frac{3}{5}.$$

---

An alternative proof goes by observing that
$$\gcd(q,n)=\gcd\Bigg(q,\frac{q+1}{2}\Bigg)=\gcd\Bigg(q,\frac{q+1}{2}\cdot{n}\Bigg)=1$$
which contradicts
$$q \mid \Bigg(\frac{q+1}{2}\cdot{n}\Bigg).$$

---

Thus, either
$$\frac{1}{2} < \frac{q+1}{2q} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{5}{8}$$
or
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{q+1}{2q} < \frac{3}{5}$$
holds.

---

Here are our:

**QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Do you see a quick way to improve on these bounds, using the ideas we have given in this post, and possibly even more?

> **(2)** If the bounds **can be** improved, can you **show** how?

> **(3)** If the bounds **cannot be** improved, can you **explain** why?

Answer (score 0):

**Adding this other answer for another perspective on the issue at hand.**

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.

Harking back from this [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284420), we have the equation
$$\frac{\sigma(N)}{\varphi(N)}=2\cdot\frac{q}{q-1}\cdot\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}$$
from which we obtain
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}}{\dfrac{\varphi(N)}{N}}=\frac{q}{q-1}$$
since $N$ is perfect implies $\sigma(N)/N=2$.

---

From the [earlier answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4318204/28816), we have that
$$\frac{3}{5} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{5}{8} \iff q = 5$$
and
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{3}{5} \iff q \geq 13.$$
Also, from the original post, we have
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{1}{2}.$$

---

We now test whether, indeed, $q=5$ follows from
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}}{\dfrac{\varphi(N)}{N}}=\frac{q}{q-1}$$
and the inequalities
$$\frac{3}{5} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{5}{8}$$
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{1}{2}.$$

So we are supposed to solve the inequality
$$\frac{6}{5} = \dfrac{(3/5)}{(1/2)} < \frac{q}{q-1} < \dfrac{(5/8)}{(120/217\zeta(3))} = \frac{217\zeta(3)}{192}.$$
Asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%2F5+%3C+q%2F%28q+-+1%29+%3C+%285%2F8%29%2F%28120%2F%28217zeta%283%29%29%29) to solve our inequality gives the solution
$$3.78882 \approx \dfrac{217\zeta(3)}{217\zeta(3) - 192} < q < 6,$$
confirming the expected $q=5$.

---

We now test whether, indeed, $q \geq 13$ follows from
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}}{\dfrac{\varphi(N)}{N}}=\frac{q}{q-1}$$
and the inequalities
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{3}{5}$$
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{1}{2}.$$

So we are supposed to solve the inequality
$$\frac{240}{217\zeta(3)} = \dfrac{(120/217\zeta(3))}{(1/2)} < \frac{q}{q-1} < \dfrac{(3/5)}{(120/217\zeta(3))} = \frac{217\zeta(3)}{200}.$$

Notice that
$$\frac{240}{217\zeta(3)} \approx 0.92$$
whence
$$\frac{240}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{q}{q-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{q-1}$$
is trivial.

Hence, we replace the lower bound by
$$1 < \frac{q}{q - 1}$$
so that we can now solve the inequality
$$1 < \frac{q}{q - 1} < \frac{217\zeta(3)}{200}.$$
Asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%3C+q%2F%28q+-+1%29+%3C+%28217zeta%283%29%29%2F200) to solve our inequality gives the solution
$$q > \dfrac{217\zeta(3)}{217\zeta(3) - 200} \approx 4.28697$$
which **neither confirms nor contradicts** the expected $q \geq 13$.

---

We now test whether, indeed, $q \geq 13$ follows from
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}}{\dfrac{\varphi(N)}{N}}=\frac{q}{q-1}$$
and the inequalities
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{120}{217\zeta(3)} < \frac{\varphi(N)}{N} < \frac{1}{2}.$$

From the previous section, it suffices to consider the inequality
$$\frac{q}{q-1} < \dfrac{(1/2)}{(120/217\zeta(3))} = \frac{217\zeta(3)}{240}.$$

We can now solve the inequality
$$1 < \frac{q}{q - 1} < \frac{217\zeta(3)}{240}.$$
Asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%3C+q%2F%28q+-+1%29+%3C+%28217zeta%283%29%29%2F240) to solve our inequality gives the solution
$$q > \dfrac{217\zeta(3)}{217\zeta(3) - 240} \approx 12.5128$$
which confirms the expected $q \geq 13$.

Answer (score -1):

**Note:  This is not really an answer, just some thoughts that recently occurred to me, that would be too long to include in the *Comments* section.**

Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.

It is known that
$$\varphi(x) < \sigma(x)$$
for all $x > 1$.  Therefore, we are sure that
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} \leq \frac{2q}{q+1}.$$

---

Now, in the original post, we have proved that
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{2} \implies q = 5.$$

Hence, we have
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{q+1}{2q} \implies \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{2} \implies q = 5 \implies \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{q+1}{2q} = \frac{5+1}{10} = \frac{3}{5}.$$

Therefore, the biconditional
$$q = 5 \iff \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{3}{5}$$
holds, assuming the inequality
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{q+1}{2q}$$
is true.

---

But we are sure that the inequality
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{2q}{q+1}$$
holds.

Assuming that
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} > \frac{q+1}{2q}$$
is true, we obtain
$$\frac{q+1}{2q} < \frac{2q}{q+1}$$
$$(q + 1)^2 < 4q^2$$
which implies that
$$3q^2 - 2q - 1 > 0$$
$$(3q + 1)(q - 1) > 0$$
from which we finally conclude that
$$q > 1,$$
which is trivial.

---

Again, we know that the inequality
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{2q}{q+1}$$
holds.

Assuming that
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < \frac{q+1}{2q}$$
then we obtain
$$\Bigg(\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}\Bigg)^2 < \Bigg(\frac{2q}{q+1}\Bigg)\cdot\Bigg(\frac{q+1}{2q}\Bigg) = 1$$
from which we get
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} < 1$$
which, again, is trivial.