# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then can $n^2 - q^k$ be a cube?

Tags: divisibility, diophantine-equations, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

This question is an offshoot of the following earlier post:

[If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $n^2 - q^k$ is not a square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121498)

My question in the present post is the following:

> If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then can $n^2 - q^k$ be a cube?

*Not much can be said without some additional hypotheses.*

In the paper titled [*Improving the Chen and Chen result for odd perfect numbers*](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf) (Lemma 8, page 7), Broughan et al. show that if
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}$$
is a square, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$, then $k=1$.  It follows that, if $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square, then $\sigma(n^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, which [implies that](https://mathoverflow.net/a/340106/10365) $q \equiv k = 1 \pmod 8$.

Since $n$ is odd, $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.  This implies that $8 \mid (n^2 - q^k)$.

Alas, this is where I get stuck.  I do not even know how to rule out the simplest case
$$n^2 - q^k = 8.$$

**An Elementary Attempt to Rule Out $n^2 - q^k = 8$**

Subtract $9$ from both sides, and transfer $q^k$ to the RHS:
$$n^2 - 9 = q^k - 1.$$

Factoring both sides, we get
$$(n+3)(n-3)=(q-1)Q$$
where $Q=\sigma(q^{k-1})$.

We get two cases:

**Case 1** $n+3 \mid (q^k - 1)$

This implies that $n + 3 \leq q^k - 1$, from which we obtain
$$n < n + 4 \leq q^k.$$

But we know from work of [Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591), [Dris (2017)](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-4/01-13/), and [Starni (2018)](http://nntdm.net/volume-24-2018/number-1/5-9/) that $q < n$ holds unconditionally.

Thus, we get
$$q < n < q^k$$
which contradicts $k=1$.

**Case 2** $n - 3 \mid (q^k - 1)$

This implies that
$$n - 3 \leq q^k - 1$$
which means that
$$n - 2 \leq q^k.$$

Again, by the results of Brown, Dris, and Starni, we have
$$q - 2 < n - 2 \leq q^k,$$
which does not contradict $k=1$.

> Can anything be said about the general case, preferably by relaxing the hypotheses?

**UPDATE (1 NOV 2019 - 08:32 AM Manila time)**

Blimey!  I did not realize that
**Case 1** $n+3 \mid (q^k - 1)$
holds in general.

Thus, under the assumption that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square, $n^2 - q^k \neq 8$.

Comment: test mod 9 maybe ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, please enlighten me, as I do not understand what you meant by your comment.

Comment: Taking remainder on division by 9, all cubes fall into 3 classes.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  So suppose $n^2 - q^k$ is a cube.  This implies that $n^2 - q^k \in \{0, 1, 8\} \pmod 9$.  But $n^2 \in \{0, 1, 4, 7\} \pmod 9$.  And then what?  Evidently, it cannot happen that both $n^2 - q^k \equiv 0 \pmod 9$ and $n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$, as this would imply that $q^k \equiv 0 \pmod 9$, which would imply that $q=3$, contradicting $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  I am not optimistic that it is similarly easy to rule out the other scenarios.  There are eleven ($11$) remaining cases.

Comment: Blimey! Since $q^k < {2n^2}/3$, a result of Dris published in JIS (2012), then $n^2 - q^k > {n^2}/3$, resulting in a large lower bound for $n^2 - q^k$ if one uses Ochem and Rao's $q^k n^2 > {10}^{1500}$ published in Math. Comp. (2012).

Answer (score 1):

Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number (**OPN**) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Suppose to the contrary that $n^2 - q^k = t^3$, for some positive integer $t$.  Since $n^2 - q^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, then $t \geq 2$.

Substituting
$$y=n$$
$$t=x$$
the condition $n^2 - q^k = t^3$ gives rise to the [Mordell curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve)
$$E: y^2 = x^3 + q^k$$
which has discriminant
$$D_E = -27{q^{2k}}.$$

By the [Nagell-Lutz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell%E2%80%93Lutz_theorem), we need to consider the possibilities
$$y \in \{\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm q, \pm 3q, \ldots, \pm q^k, \pm 3q^k\}.$$

Since $\gcd(y,q)=\gcd(n,q)=1$, then
$$y \not\in \{\pm q, \pm 3q, \ldots, \pm q^k, \pm 3q^k\}.$$

Additionally, since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $q \geq 5$.  By work of [Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591), [Dris (2017)](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-4/01-13/), and [Starni (2018)](http://nntdm.net/volume-24-2018/number-1/5-9/), we know that $n > q$.  It follows that
$$y = n > q \geq 5,$$
so that we have
$$y \not\in \{\pm 1, \pm 3\}.$$

> <s>We therefore conclude that the elliptic curve
> $$E : y^2 = x^3 + q^k$$
> does not have any lattice points satisfying the **OPN** constraints.  It follows that the equation
> $$n^2 - q^k = t^3$$
> does not have any positive integral solutions, if $q^k n^2$ is an **OPN** with special prime $q$.</s>

<s>In particular, this appears to settle **Conjecture 6.2** and **Conjecture 6.3** on page 6 of this [preprint (Dris, San Diego (2020))](https://easychair.org/publications/preprint/1R2G).</s>

**Edit (July 31, 2020 - 9:44 AM Manila time)** It remains to consider the interesting non-torsion integer points.