# Follow-up to question 3121498, asked in February 2019

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form (i.e. $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$).  Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121498) (and the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122247/28816) contained therein) presented a proof of the following proposition, the first conditional on the hypothesis that $\sigma(m^2)/p^k$ is a square, and the second one was unconditional:

> If $n = p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then $m^2 - p^k$ is not a square.

In both proofs, the equation $p^k + 1 = 2m$ was obtained, and was shown to lead to a contradiction.

Here are my questions:

> **(1)**  Does the contradiction imply that the inequation $p^k + 1 \neq 2m$ holds for all odd perfect numbers $n = p^k m^2$, in general?

> **(2)**  If the answer to Question **(1)** is *YES*, which of the following inequalities hold in general for an odd perfect number?

> > (a) $p^k + 1 < 2m$; or

> > (b) $p^k + 1 > 2m$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I figured this much from this closely related [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/376268), where we tried to disprove the Dris Conjecture (that $p^k < m$) and therefore the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture  (that $k=1$) in one fell swoop.  However, we were unsuccessful, as [Pascal Ochem](https://mathoverflow.net/users/71090) pointed out that our method required that $p^k \geq 2m - 1$.

Comment: Would the quick downvoter care to explain his/her downvote please?  Some form of feedback, hopefully constructive, would go a long way towards improving future questions/posts of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer, which proves that $p^k + 1 \neq 2m$ holds in general for all odd perfect numbers.

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.

Suppose to the contrary that $p^k + 1 = 2m$.

Then $m^2 - p^k = m^2 - (2m - 1) = m^2 - 2m + 1 = (m - 1)^2$, which contradicts the proposition in the **OP**.