# If $k=1$, then the index of an odd perfect number $p^k n^2$ (as defined by Chen and Chen (2014)) is not squarefree.

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

In what follows, we let $\sigma=\sigma_1$ denote the *classical sum-of-divisors* function.  Denote the *deficiency* function of the positive integer $x$ by $D(x)=2(x)-\sigma(x)$, and the *aliquot sum* of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$.

Suppose that $N$ is an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) and $q^\alpha$ is a prime power with $q^\alpha \parallel N$.

(Euler proved that $N$ can be written in the Eulerian form $p^k n^2$ where $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,n)=1$.)

Define the index $m = \sigma(N/q^\alpha)/q^\alpha$.  [Chen and Chen (2014)](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/colloquium-mathematicum/all/136/1/88031/on-the-index-of-an-odd-perfect-number) proved that, if $q = p$, then $m$ cannot take any of the $30$ forms

> $$q_1, {q_1}^2, {q_1}^3, {q_1}^4, {q_1}^5, {q_1}^6, {q_1}^7, {q_1}^8, q_1 q_2, {q_1}^2 q_2, {q_1}^3 q_2, {q_1}^4 q_2, {q_1}^5 q_2, {q_1}^2 {q_2}^2, {q_1}^3 {q_2}^2, {q_1}^4 {q_2}^2, q_1 q_2 q_3, {q_1}^2 q_2 q_3, {q_1}^3 q_2 q_3,$$
> $${q_1}^4 q_2 q_3, {q_1}^2 {q_2}^2 q_3, {q_1}^2 {q_2}^2 {q_3}^2, q_1 q_2 q_3 q_4, {q_1}^2 q_2 q_3 q_4, {q_1}^3 q_2 q_3 q_4, {q_1}^2 {q_2}^2 q_3 q_4, q_1 q_2 q_3 q_4 q_5, {q_1}^2 q_2 q_3 q_4 q_5, q_1 q_2 q_3 q_4 q_5 q_6, q_1 q_2 q_3 q_4 q_5 q_6 q_7$$

where $q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4, q_5, q_6, q_7$ are distinct odd primes.  (A similar result is proved if $q \neq p$.)

This seems to suggest the following question:

**INITIAL QUESTION**

> Can it be **unconditionally** proven that the index $m$ of an odd perfect number cannot be squarefree?

**MOTIVATION / MY ATTEMPT**

Let $N = p^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special/Eulerian prime $p$ (i.e. $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,n) = 1$).

Then we have
$$\sigma(p^k)\sigma(n^2) = \sigma(p^k n^2) = \sigma(N) = 2N = 2 p^k n^2$$
so that
$$\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{p^k} = n^2.$$

Suppose that $k = 1$. We obtain
$$D(n^2) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{p} = \frac{n^2}{(p + 1)/2},$$
where we have set $k = 1$ in
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(p^k)} = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{p^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(p^k)/2}.$$

But Acquaah and Konyagin proved in [(IJNT, 2012)](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S1793042112500935) that the implication
$$k = 1 \implies p < n\sqrt{3}$$
holds.

Together with the implication
$$k > 1 \implies p < n$$
proved by Dris in [(JIS, 2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), we obtain the unconditional estimate $p < n\sqrt{3}$.

For simplicity in the computations, we will use the (weaker) estimate $p < 2n$ instead.

First, note that $p \neq 2m - 1$, since
$$m = \frac{p+1}{2} \iff m^2 - p^k = m^2 - p = \left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right)^2 - p = \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2 \text{ is a square}$$
will contradict "$m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square**". (See: [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4692359) and [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121498).)

This means that
$$k = 1 \implies p < 2n-1 \implies p+1 < 2n \implies \sigma(p) < 2n \implies \sigma(p^k) < 2n$$
$$\implies D(n^2) = \frac{D(n^2)}{s(p^k)} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(p^k)} > n$$

Now, the condition $k = 1$ is [equivalent](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01868) to $D(n^2) \mid n^2$.

Since $D(n^2)$ is squarefree, we may write
$$D(n^2) = \operatorname{rad(D(n^2)}) \mid n^2$$
from which it follows that
$$D(n^2) = \operatorname{rad(D(n^2)}) \mid n.$$

But then this implies that
$$n < D(n^2) \leq n,$$
which is a contradiction.

Hence, we conclude that if $k=1$, then the index $m = \sigma(N/q^\alpha)/q^\alpha$ where $q=p$ ($p$ is the special/Eulerian prime) is **not squarefree**.

**FOLLOW-UP QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Do you see an obvious (alternative) way of proving my assertion above?

> **(2)** Can you remove the condition $k=1$ and still prove that the index is **not squarefree** for $q=p$?

> **(3)** If the answer to Question **(2)** is *YES*, can you extend the proof to include the case $q \neq p$?

Comment: There are no known odd perfect numbers, and it is quite possible there are no such numbers at all.

Comment: @MarkVSapir: Point taken.  However, what would happen to your argument if there is an odd perfect number?

Comment: I do not have an argument. I just don't see a reason to talk about the empty set.

Comment: @MarkVSapir:  If you do not have a proof, then I do not understand how you can plainly say that the set of odd perfect numbers is empty.  =)