# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, then $n^2 - q^k = 2^r t$ implies that $3 \leq r$ is odd. Therefore?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, perfect-numbers, open-problem

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Let $N$ be an odd perfect number given in the so-called *Eulerian form* $N = q^k n^2$ where $q$ is the *special prime* satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121498) that $n^2 - q^k$ is not a square.  (Note that $n^2 - q^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ is true since $n$ odd implies that $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ holds.  In particular, we may write $n^2 - q^k = 2^r t$, where $\gcd(2,t)=1$ since $n^2 - q^k$ is not squarefree.)

---

> Since $n^2 - q^k = 2^r t$ is not a square and $\gcd(2,t)=1$, then $3 \leq r$ is odd.  Therefore, since $n$ is odd implies that $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ holds, and since $2^r t \equiv 0 \pmod 8$, it follows that $q^k \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.  Hence, we infer that $q \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ holds, by considering the various possibilities for $q \pmod 8$ and $k \pmod 8$, where we note that $q$ and $k$ are both **odd**.  (Furthermore, they are both congruent to $1 \pmod 4$, but that will not matter in the argument.) $\tag{1}$

---

Consequently, $q \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ rules out $q = 5$ **and** $q = 13$.  We therefore conclude that $q \geq 17$.

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** I have doubts about the logical validity of the argument in the section marked with a $(1)$.  Is the proof logically sound?  If it is not, how can it be mended so as to produce a correct proof?

---

I would have included a table showing **all of the possibilities** for $q \pmod 8$ and $k \pmod 8$, and computing $q^k$ for each such possibility, but I have forgotten how to typeset tables using MathJAX.  I hope this is OK.

---

**Updated - January 22, 2023 - 18:04 PM (Manila time)**

> While the argument in the original post is flawed, we do get $3 \leq r$ under the *additional hypothesis* that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square.  (Please see [[Dris and San Diego (2020), pages 31-32]](https://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-2/27-33/).)

Comment: Why "$3\leq r$ is odd" ? For example, when $(r,t)=(2,3)$, $2^rt$ is not a square.

Comment: Well technically yes, @mathlove.  However, I also know that $n^2 - q^k = 2^r t > \frac{3373n^2}{3375}$, so I guess that rules out your counterexample?

Comment: Ahh yes, now I get your point, @mathlove!  If you could just please write out an answer, I will be more than glad to upvote and then accept it.  Thanks!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can conclude that "$3\leq r$ is odd".

For $r=2$ and any non-square odd integer $t$, $n^2-q^k=2^{r}t$ is not a square.

---

By the way, one can prove that $q^k\equiv 1\pmod 8$ implies $q\equiv 1\pmod 8$ as follows :
$$1\equiv q^k\equiv q\cdot (q^2)^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\equiv q\cdot 1^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\equiv q\pmod 8$$

Answer (score 1):

Sounds sound enough, but the fact $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod8$ sounds a little confusing in my opinion, so putting the fact out that $q^k\equiv 1\pmod8$ should come first, and then $2^rt \equiv 0\pmod 8$, and then $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod8$.

However, take all of this advice with a grain of salt as it is with personal opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @ANeutrinoBoy!  The fact that $q^k \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ is **derived** from $2^r t \equiv 0 \pmod 8$ and $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.  The fact that $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ follows from the fact that $n$ is odd - indeed, it suffices to consider the residue classes $n \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, $n \equiv 3 \pmod 8$, $n \equiv 5 \pmod 8$, and $n \equiv 7 \pmod 8$.